# PostgreSQL, Psycopg, Amundsen not working

Tags: python, postgresql

I am running Windows 10 and WSL2.  I have PostgreSQL 15 running.  I can use psql to access a new data base and tables.  I am attempting to use Amundsen to access the PostgreSQL database.  Amundsen attempts to use psycopg2 to access PostgreSQL.  I get an error and am told that the connection was refused.

I wrote a small application in Python to test the connection.  That code follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#test postgres connection
import psycopg2
print ("Content-type: text\html")
print()
conn = psycopg2.connect("\
    dbname='Titanic'\
    user='jdwbmc'\
    host='localhost'\
    password='secret'\
");
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
records = c.fetchall()
import pprint
pprint.pprint(records)
```

The connection information works in psql, but this application returns the same error seen from Amundsen.  The connection is refused.  I've tried several versions of the code, but nothing seems to work.  Thoughts?

Comment: If `dbname` is case-sensitive then should be `"Titanic"`, otherwise - `titanic`

Comment: To your question add the following : 1) `psycopg2` version  and how it was installed. 2) The complete error message. 3) The `psql` connection command used. 4) Where you are running the Python code, locally or remote?

Comment: 1. I have removed the backslashes, but I get the same error.

Comment: 1. I have removed the backslashes, but I get the same error. 2. Yes, it actually is a capital T in the database name.  3. psycopg2 is installed by Amundsen, so I'm not quite sure of the version.  I've tried to install my own with pip, but to no avail.

Comment: The error is as follows: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestPostgres2.py", line 3, in <module>
    con = psycopg2.connect(
  File "/mnt/c/Users/jdwbm/Documents/Amundsen/amundsen/databuilder/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: I am running PostgreSQL15 and the psql is the version offered in the pull down menu in Windows.  I am running the code in the same place Amundsen would call it: jdwbmc@Pugio:/mnt/c/Users/jdwbm/Documents/Amundsen/amundsen/databuilder